# Kind of web services and how to call them from an iphone

Tags: iphone, web-services

I'm not able to understand the process of calling web services from my iphone application.

Please explain the procedure for calling web services in my iphone application in detail:

- How to send request to webservices
- How to parse the responses
- Which protocol is used to send the request
- Which parser is used to retrive the response

Also explain what is SOAP, JSON, HTTP GET & POST, XML and what is the purpose of all these.

I'd be very happy if you send some code for calling web services in iphone application for my easy understanding.

Thank you.

Comment: The question as is, is too broad and your tag too narrow.  It won't help you to describe all this as it matters more what exact services you want to call.

Comment: how can i send request for adding to numbers using HTTP request and how to retrive the result from web service using xml parser and how to show the result in my iphone...

Comment: plz give me a detail explanation...i'm very happy if u r sending the sample application for this...

thank u...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP and REST are web services.. JSON and XML are the formats they (webservices) returns..

you can find about SOAP and REST here.. 
http://www.taranfx.com/rest-vs-soap-using-http-choosing-the-right-webservice-protocol

find xml and json here.
http://www.subbu.org/blog/2006/08/json-vs-xml

If you are looking for consuming SOAP in iPhone you can read my blog here.
http://www.makebetterthings.com/blogs/iphone/call-soap-web-service-from-iphone/

Comment: thank u Saurabh...can u giv me a sample application for,

how can i send request for adding to numbers using HTTP request and how to retrive the result from web service using xml parser and how to show the result in my iphone...plz...